# How to mock a method which is called by another method using EasyMock?

Tags: java, easymock

I need to mock a method inside a void method.

Here is my sample code:

```java
class MyClass {

    public MyClass(Session s, Boolean b1, Boolean b2)

    void myMethod(some paramaters...) {

        // some code
        int count= setSize();
    }

    int setSize() {

        // some calculation....
        return size;
    }
```

Now in my test class I want to mock `setSize()` to return my own value say `300`.

I did like:

```java
MyClass mockclass = createNiceMock(MyClass.class);
EasyMock.expect(mockimplyZero.setBatchSize()).andReturn(Integer.valueOf(300));

mockclass.myMethod(parameters....)
```

when call `myMethod`, it's not going properly into the method.
I think it might be EasyMock is setting default values to the `MyClass` constructor. How to do the mock correctly?

There are no methods in `MyClass` except constructor, `myMethod` and `setSize`

Comment: Hint: please read about java naming conventions. Method names go camelCase; so do fields; but class names go UpperCase. That is important; as deviating from these standards makes your code **harder** to read for other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using partial mocking. Here is an example close to your code.

First the tested class. You will need to create a partial mock of it. `getSize` should be mocked, but `myMethod` should since it is the tested method.

Also, frequently, you will want to call a constructor to initialize the class correctly (a classical mock won't call any constructor).

```
class MyClass {

  private boolean b1;
  private boolean b2;

  public MyClass(boolean b1, boolean b2) {
    this.b1 = b1;
    this.b2 = b2;
  }

  int myMethod() {
    return getSize();
  }

  int getSize() {
    return 42;
  }

  public boolean getB1() {
    return b1;
  }

  public boolean getB2() {
    return b2;
  }
}
```

The test will then be the following

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MyClassTest {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    // Create a partial mock by calling its constructor
    // and only mocking getSize
    MyClass mock = createMockBuilder(MyClass.class)
        .withConstructor(true, true)
        .addMockedMethod("getSize")
        .createMock();

    // Record that getSize should return 8 (instead of 42)
    expect(mock.getSize()).andReturn(8);

    // All recording done. So put the mock in replay mode
    replay(mock);

    // Then, these assertions are to prove that the partial mock is 
    // actually doing what we expect. This is just to prove my point. Your
    // actual code will verify that myMethod is doing was is expected

    // 1. Verify that the constructor was correctly called
    assertEquals(true, mock.getB1());
    assertEquals(true, mock.getB2());
    // 2. Verify that getSize was indeed mocked 
    assertEquals(8, mock.myMethod());

    // Check everything expected was indeed called
    verify(mock);
  }
}
```

Job done. Note that this isn't necessarily a sign of bad design. I frequently use it when testing the [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

You should not mock **one** method while testing another method on the **same** class. You could theoretically do that (using a Mokito [spy](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mockito/mockito-spy-example/)
for example).

In that sense, you are approaching this on a wrong level: you actually should not care which other methods your method under test calls within your class under test. But if you have to adapt things for testing, then the way to go would be (for example) a method that allows your test code to setup that **size** field prior invoking `mymethod()`.

Or: you separate concerns, and move that "size" part into its own class X. And then your class under test could hold an instance of X; and that instance could then be mocked.

Long story short: you want to step back and read some tutorials on how to use EasyMock. This not something that you can learn by trial and error.

Comment: ohh is it... I should somehow mock this setSize() as its calling webservice internally, and its failing during testing.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: That *very much* depends on the things you actually want to do. But believe me: your current approach is **not** a reasonable design. Dont try to enforce this approach; just because it is the one that you currently have in your code. You better step back and learn how to do such things the "right" way; otherwise EasyMock will not much value to your testing activities; and in the end make you feel like "this unit testing stuff doesnt work".

Comment: In other words: maybe you also want to step back and learn about doing TDD (test driven development) ... because it is always harder to write tests for code that wasnt written to be testable. Using TDD, that cant happen - because you write tests prior writing production code.